# List: Insert new item after the currently pointed to item

Tags: c#

I am currently working/experimenting with lists. I am able to determine with function `GetNextTree` the position of each item in my list such as: `First`, `Next` and `Last`. I have an already made list from an array `ax` but now I am trying to implement an insert button that will take values `tree_type`, `tree_height`, `tree_price`, `tree_instock` and create the item. Since I can point anywhere in my list, the insert will be intended to add an item after the currently pointed to item. That is where my question is: How can I add a new item `after` the currently pointed to item?

```
public class fruit_trees
{
    private string tree_type = " ";
    private int tree_height = 0;
    public double tree_price = 0;
    private int tree_instock = 0;


    public fruit_trees next_tree;

    public fruit_trees(string newtree, int newheight, double newprice, int newinstock)
    {
        tree_type = newtree;
        tree_height = newheight;
        tree_price = newprice;
        tree_instock = newinstock;


        next_tree = null;
    }

    public string GetTreeType
    {
        get { return tree_type;
            }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return tree_type + " " + tree_height + " " + tree_price + " " + tree_instock;

    }

}

public class ListForTrees
{
    private fruit_trees first_tree;
    public fruit_trees First_tree
    {
        get
        {
            return first_tree;
        }
    }

    public fruit_trees last_tree;
    public int current;
    public int count = 0;



    public ListForTrees(fruit_trees new_tree)
    {
        first_tree = new_tree;
        last_tree = new_tree;
        count = 1;
        current = 0;
    }

    public ListForTrees(IEnumerable trees)
    {
        current = 0;
        foreach (fruit_trees t in trees)
        {
            this.AddTree(t);
        }
    }

    public fruit_trees GetNextTree()
    {
        //current = 0;
        fruit_trees ft = first_tree;

        if (current == count)
        {

            current = 0;
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (i != current)
        {
            ft = ft.next_tree;
            i++;

        }

        return ft;
    }

}

ListForTrees mainlist = new ListForTrees();
private void BtnInsertTree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        int height = Convert.ToInt32(TxtTreeHeight.Text);
        int stock = Convert.ToInt32(TxtTreeStock.Text);
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(TxtTreePrice.Text);

        fruit_trees treeadd = new fruit_trees(TxtTreeName.Text, height, price, stock);
        mainlist.AddTree(treeadd);

    }
    catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please check intput fields");
    }
}

private void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fruit_trees[] ax = {   new fruit_trees("cherry", 48, 12.95, 3),
                           new fruit_trees("pine", 36, 9.95, 8),
                           new fruit_trees("oak", 60, 14.95, 2),
                           new fruit_trees("peach", 54, 19.95, 3),
                           new fruit_trees("pear", 36, 11.85, 2),
                           new fruit_trees("apple", 62, 13.45, 5)
                       };

    mainlist = new ListForTrees(ax);
    fruit_trees current = mainlist.First_tree;
    while (current != null)
    {
        TxtOutput.AppendText(current.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        current = current.next_tree;
    }

}

private void ShowFirstItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Show Next Item
    labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.First_tree.GetTreeType;
}

private void ShowNextItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    fruit_trees obj = mainlist.GetNextTree();
    if (obj.next_tree == null)
    {
        labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.First_tree.GetTreeType.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        mainlist.current++;
        labelSpecificTree.Text = obj.next_tree.GetTreeType.ToString();
    }

}

private void ShowLastItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Show First Item
    labelSpecificTree.Text = mainlist.last_tree.GetTreeType;

}
```

Comment: u should also practice for naming conventions.

Comment: Just because he doesn't agree with your convention doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: @CodeLover1985 You should reduce the code to the smallest amount that demonstrates what you are trying to ask. None of us want to look at ~150 lines of code to figure out what's going on. Furthermore, you don't seem to have given us enough details of the ListForTrees class for us to even answer your question.

Comment: @CrazyCasta yes, I tried taking all the unnecessary code, anything else i omit will be seen as out of context. Summary: I want insert a new item after `current` item.

Comment: @CodeLover1985 No, you haven't taken out nearly enough code. As far as I can tell, half of that code does not relate to inserting trees. We do not need to know what the tree class has, that's not relevant to inserting trees (unless it's a linked list, which it doesn't appear to be). Second, you have no definition for AddTree, so we have no idea what your data-structure is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm slightly confused by what's going on here. You're implementing your own `ArrayList` like class which is not really a list at all... I don't really see the point of doing such things in C# but alright... Here's the method;

```
  fruit_trees[] InsertNode(fruit_trees current, fruit_trees nNode)
  {
       fruit_trees[] temp = new fruit_trees[ax.Length + 1];
       int i = 0;

       while (ax[i] != current)
       {
             temp[i] = ax[i];
             i++;
       }
       temp[i+1] = nNode;
       while (i < ax.Length)
       {
            temp[i+1] = ax[i];
       }

       return temp; 
  }
```

call this like such;

```
  ax = InsertNode(current, nNode);
```

What we're doing is making a new list with one extra slot, copying each `fruit_tree` over til we hit the node we want to insert after, then we copy the new tree in. After that we copy over the rest of the old array. Then we return the new array.